# cannot decode object of class (SKCameraNode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (SKCameraNode)'

I get this error when I'm trying to run the app from my phone through USB.
I have Xcode 8 and iOS 8 and it works perfectly fine on simulator.
Can I fix it without upgrading the iOS?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the iOS 8 Simulator? It looks like SKCameraNode was introduced in iOS 9, so I'd be very surprised if it works well in the Simulator – unless it's a Simulator for iOS 10, as is the Xcode 8 default.

In short, no, I think you'll need to update your phone to run the app.

Comment: No.. I use the default iOS 10 simulator. So this means that all my apps will be running on iOS 9 and later? I could not create apps for iOS 8 too? (sorry if it's out of topic)

Comment: Your Xcode project has a setting for the minimum required iOS version. It's called "Deployment Target," and it defaults to the latest version of iOS. You can create apps for older versions of iOS by changing this setting – but that means you won't be able to use classes introduced in later versions without some extra checks. In this case, you could set your Deployment Target to iOS 8, but then would have to guard or remove references to SKCameraNode because it wasn't available in iOS 8.